# Relational models in Treeline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, treeline

I'm setting up models in a new Treeline app and I'm curious how to setup relationships between models. For instance, I have a model called "Landlord" and I have a model called "Property". A landlord can have multiple properties so how should I go about setting up a one-to-many relationship? Do I need to do anything or is Treeline going to figure it out for me?

Comment: A diagram, screenshot or some code above and beyond a textual description would go a long way to making this question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treeline doesn't support model relationships (aka associations) in beta.  You can implement them yourself by defining a foreign key for your model (e.g. a `landlord` attribute in the `Property` model).  Then you can find all of a Landlord's properties by using the `List Properties` machine with the criteria set to:

```
{
  "landlord": <some landlord id>
}
```